# Using least squares straight line fitting on experimental data with errors

Tags: regression, data-visualization, measurement-error

I'm trying to fit a line into a graph with points that have errors both in the y and x directions. I found the following document on the subject:

https://www.che.udel.edu/pdf/FittingData.pdf

My problem is that I don't quite understand what the author means on page 8 with:

> To use this method, you must first establish the standard error of each point; this quantity will be called e_i. If you made repeat measurements, you should use the standard deviation."

How can I compute the standard error for each point exactly?

Could someone give an example, how I come up with the standard errors if I have, say, the next set of data:

```
x = [2, 4, 6], x_error = [0.2, 0.15, 0.1]
y = [1, 3, 5], y_error = [0.1, 0.12, 0.2]
```

I want to at least take into account the y_error when fitting the line.

Comment: I got so far, that I understand now that for accounting the y-error, I just use the y error for each y as the weight in the sums present in the equations. Can I also account the x errors somehow into the weight?

Comment: You probably don't want to use ordinary least squares on this problem - it's for the case where only the y's have errors. If the x's have errors as well, it's biased, sometimes quite badly. Good search terms include `errors in variables regression`, `Deming regression`, `Model II regression`, `Total least squares` and `orthogonal regression` (which are not all exactly the same thing but are related in one way or another). Searching on those here and more widely may help you identify some more appropriate approaches.